# Overriding UserChangeForm in django

Tags: python, django

Due to the fact that i don't need to edit all the fields in my form i ve searched for a way to exclude some fields from Userchangeform and i found out that overriding the forms works

**forms.py**

```
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm

class UserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email',)
```

the problem is that i need to delete that message after the email input
[image: delete the yellow message from the form]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need to use the `UserChangeForm` in this case. See the source of the class:

```
class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField(
        label=_("Password"),
        help_text=_(
            "Raw passwords are not stored, so there is no way to see this "
            "user's password, but you can change the password using "
            "<a href=\"{}\">this form</a>."
        ),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
        field_classes = {'username': UsernameField}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        password = self.fields.get('password')
        if password:
            password.help_text = password.help_text.format('../password/')
        user_permissions = self.fields.get('user_permissions')
        if user_permissions:
            user_permissions.queryset = user_permissions.queryset.select_related('content_type')

    def clean_password(self):
        # Regardless of what the user provides, return the initial value.
        # This is done here, rather than on the field, because the
        # field does not have access to the initial value
        return self.initial["password"]
```

90% of the extra code is related to the password you don't want, and some for permissions and username. So for your needs just extending `ModelForm` is enough.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm

class UserChangeForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email',)
```